# AsyncTask with Progress bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, zxing

I have an application with 3 or more AsycTask that are called sequentially. Because these asyntasks are all similar, I created a separated class and it works properly.

Now I would like to add a progress bar in order to show something when these asynctasks ask and process the result...but not work.

My application work as follow:

1. I open my camera and with ZXing library I decode a qrCode
2. using HttpRequest I ask to my server some informations and my application processes these informations

The point is that during the processing my application shows a black screen with the tipical viewfinder of ZXing library (I think that you understand what I mean). How can replace this view with another block with a progress bar?

I already tried to modified the progress bar visibility, on the event *onPreExecute* and *onPostExecute*, also I tried to use the event *onProgressUpdate*, but nothig is change. The viewfinder remains on the screen until the asyncTask is not finish.
Follow my code for execute the AsyncTask:

```
response = asynkTaskDeleteMissionQueue.execute().get();
```

and my AsyncTask class

```html
package com.klainrobotics.lucalombardi.krmir;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Created by Luca Lombardi on 27/11/2017.
 */

public class MiRCall extends AsyncTask <String, Void, List<Object> >{
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    private String url;
    private String method;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    public MiRCall(Context v, ProgressBar prg, String...params){
        method = params[0];
        url = params[1];
        progress = prg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(v);

    }


    @Override
    protected List<Object> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        int result = -1;
        publishProgress();

        List<Object> response = new Vector<Object>();
        String jsonResponse = "";

        BufferedReader br;

        try {
            URL urlMissionQueue = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlMissionQueue.openConnection();
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.setRequestMethod(method);
                connection.setRequestProperty(Costanti.headers, Costanti.StringaHeader());
                connection.setRequestProperty(Costanti.contentType, Costanti.contentTypeJSon);
                customBody(connection);

                connection.connect();
                result = connection.getResponseCode();
                response.add(result);

                if (200 <= result && result <= 299) {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                } else {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                }

                for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; jsonResponse += line);

                response.add(jsonResponse);

            }else {
                Log.e("Url", "Connection is null");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MiRCall", "doInBackgound: " + ex.toString());
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> result) {

        if (delegate != null) {
                delegate.processFinish(result);
        } else {
            Log.e("MiRCall", "You have not assigned AsyncTask delegate");
        }
    }

    public void customBody(HttpURLConnection connection) throws ProtocolException {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does publishProgress() does ? You can't update ui elements in doInBackground() function

Answer (score 0):

```
response = asynkTaskDeleteMissionQueue.execute().get();
```

Pretty bad to use the .get() function on it. Do away with get(). Only start the task.

```
asynkTaskDeleteMissionQueue.execute();
```

Then in onPostExecute() handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. I execute

```
response = asynkTaskDeleteMissionQueue.execute().get();
```

because my asyncTask returns a list of object, so I don't know another way....

And about the original question? Any suggestions?

Thanks in any case for your time